# How to Implement Custom Queue (Typescript) and NodeJS Cluster

Tags: node.js, typescript, queue

I'm implementing a custom Queue Data Structure with Typesript and populating it in index.ts file. After clustering the node, I would like to run **getMovie()** function in every cluster in parallel.

But it dequeues same number multiple times and sending in it getMovie() function as api call.

index.ts

```
import cluster from "cluster";
import os from "os";
import axios from "axios";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Movie from "./models/movie";
import { Queue } from "./ds/queue";
dotenv.config();

const cpuCount = os.cpus().length;

const itemIdNumbers: Queue<number> = new Queue<number>();
const added:number[] = [];

const delay = async (num: number): Promise<any> => {
 return new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
  resolve(setTimeout(() => {}, num));
});
};

const populateQueue = () => {
  itemIdNumbers.clear();
  for (let index = 1208530; index >= 1; index--) {
  itemIdNumbers.enqueue(index);
}
};

const insertMovie = async (movieData: any, id: number) => {
  const m = Object.assign({}, movieData);
  m.permalink_id = id;
  const movie = new Movie(m);
  await movie.save();
};

const getMovie = async () => {
  const id = itemIdNumbers.dequeue();
  axios
    .get(
      url+"/"+id
    )
    .then(async (result) => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        await insertMovie(result.data, id!);
        console.log(id, "Added");
      } else {
        console.log(id, "Not Found!");
      }
      if (itemIdNumbers.size() > 0) {
        await delay(1000);
        getMovie();
      }
    })
    .catch(async (err) => {
      console.log(id, err.message);
      await delay(1000);
      if (itemIdNumbers.size() > 0) {
        getMovie();
      }
    });
};

populateQueue();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI as string)
  .then(() => {
    if (cluster.isPrimary) {
      console.log(`Number of CPUs is ${cpuCount}`);
      console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

      for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
      }

      cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
        cluster.fork();
      });
    } else {
      getMovie();
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("DB Connection Error : ", err.message));
```

queue.ts

```
   interface IQueue<T> {
  enqueue(item: T): void;
  dequeue(): T | undefined;
  get(): T | undefined;
  clear(): void;
  size(): number;
}

export class Queue<T> implements IQueue<T> {
  private collection: T[] = [];
  private count: number = 0;

  clear(): void {
    this.collection = [];
  }

  enqueue(item: T): void {
    this.collection.push(item);
    this.count++;
  }
  dequeue(): T | undefined {
    if (this.size() > 0) {
      const dequeued = this.collection.pop();

      if (typeof dequeued !== "undefined") {
        this.count--;
      }

      return dequeued;
    }

    return undefined;
  }
  get(): T | undefined {
    if (this.size() > 0) {
      return this.collection[this.collection.length - 1];
    }

    return undefined;
  }
  size(): number {
    return this.count;
  }
}
```

I'd prefer to use Queue for this operation to prevent the system from getting duplicate records from api.